# How to hide menu icon from ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to hide the menu Button (3 vertical dots) from ActionBar, I created custom action bar but some devices still showing default menu icon on right side ActionBar.

I just want to hide menu Button (3 vertical dots) but not the menu functionality.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: It's called [action overflow](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#ActionButtons) and it is controlled by Android itself. *"The overflow icon only appears on phones that have no menu hardware keys. Phones with menu keys display the action overflow when the user presses the key."*

Answer (score 1):

It is called a `Overflow` and one way to hide it is overriding your `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method and find the overflow button and set its visibility to false

**sample:**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
       menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings).setVisible(false);
       return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: Well, `R.id.action_settings` is not really the overflow button. It is only a menu item which is **not** displayed as action button, and thus go into overflow.

Comment: @AndrewT. you are right, thank for pointing that out, change it to R.id.menu_settings to specify the overflow button

Answer (score 0):

get the menu icon at the extreme right of the action bar

Either:

```
You have defined items to appear in the overflow area, in which case, get rid of those, or

Your android:targetSdkVersion is under 11, in which case, raise it
```

see this post for more information
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html